# Changing a drawable and set it as drawableLeft

Tags: android, bitmap, drawable

I have a button in a LinearLayout where I assign a drawableLeft in XML like this:

```
<Button android:id="@+id/button_news"
    style="@style/main_button"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/news"
    android:text="@string/button_news" />
```

This works fine and the button looks like expected.

[image]

I want to change the image programmatically to show the number of news available. This is the code I have:

```
private void updateNewsButton()
{
    // load the original bitmap and draw the number of news on it to show it
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor( Statics.COLOR_GENERAL_HIGHLIGHT );
    paint.setTextAlign( Paint.Align.CENTER );
    paint.setTextSize( 24 );
    paint.setTypeface( Typeface.defaultFromStyle( Typeface.BOLD ) );
    paint.setAntiAlias( true );

    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource( getResources(), R.drawable.news ).copy( Config.ARGB_8888, true );
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas( bmp );
    int count = 5;    // TODO: load from database
    canvas.drawText( Integer.toString( count ), bmp.getWidth() / 2, bmp.getHeight() / 2, paint );
    Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable( bmp );
    _btnNews.setCompoundDrawables( d, null, null, null );
}
```

The image on my button just disappears after running the above code. I can't see what I'm doing wrong, because I've used the similare technique for an ImageView before. In there everything is the same except the last two lines. For the ImageView I just assign the bitmap directly:

```
...
imageView.setImageBitmap( bmp );
```

I need to use the drawableLeft here, because there are a few other bottons, so I can't use an ImageView again.

Any idea what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Have you tried using setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds  ?

Comment: Not until your comment. Now there is an image, but smaller then the one before. I guess I'll have to set the bounds to 0 before setting the drawable. Have to check it.... Thanks so far.

Comment: Adding the line `d.setBounds( 0, 0, 0, 0 );` did not change anything. Any other value positive or negative does also not change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put the image on left in a button programmatically, use the code below

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mybutton);   
button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.img, 0, 0, 0);
```

where the position is like this (left, top, right, bottom)